# Beginner's mind vs. a beginner's mind

Tags: nouns

I have encountered the following sentence:

> It’s important to maintain **beginner’s mind** and openness as much as
> possible.

What does "beginner's mind" represent? Mind of a beginner (without any article for mind)? or the mind of a beginner?

It would be easy to understand if the phrase was a beginner's mind, which would supposedly denote "the mind of a beginner."

More generally, regarding phrases that contain the structure "article (or no article) + noun (possessive-form) + noun"--for example, year's end, a year's end, etc.--are there rules on the use and choice of the article? Although, supposedly and logically, the article should be there for the second one, which noun exactly does the article belong to?

If "a year's end" is the same with "the end of a year, and "the year's end" with "the end of the year," then what about "year's end?" I cannot point out what it is because "end" should have an article.

Please tell us general rules on the structure "noun+noun," particularly regarding the use and choice of its article.

Comment: The sentence sounds awkward and probably has a typo.  They probably meant "a beginner's mind" to indicate the mind of the reader should remain like that of a beginner.

Comment: How about "year's end?"I think this phrase is widely used by news media and other fields.

Comment: It's used to indicate a point in time, where "beginner's mind" is not.  Might have something to do with it.  Think of "I will not be here for year's end." It is used as an event, same as Christmas or New Years.

Answer (score 1):

The ordinary way to express this in English includes an article:

"It’s important to maintain **a** beginner’s mind and openness as much as possible."

However, this isn't standard usage because "beginner's mind" is a translation for [Shoshin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoshin), which "refers to having an attitude of openness, eagerness, and lack of preconceptions when studying a subject, even when studying at an advanced level, just as a beginner would."

You would not say "It’s important to maintain **a** Shoshin". *

So, "beginner's mind" is being elevated to something like a [set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase) or a general concept like "openness" which doesn't require an article.

Comment: The sentence is from an Mckinsey&Co. article(https://www.mckinsey.com/featured-insights/mckinsey-books/author-talks-poet-maggie-smith-on-loss-creativity-and-change). Nothing to do with what you have described as "shoshin."

Comment: @user48754, not necessarily different. The same author has probably read books about eastern philosophy, or psychology books which have been influenced by it, and so the "beginner's mind" meme gets passed on.